# Modifying Virtual Images Offline

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, vmware-converter

I'm new to this vmware stuff.  I was wondering if anyone knows how to modify virtual images offline or know of any tools.  I used VM Converter to convert my current desktop to an image.  This is for a school project to be able to make changes to the image offline such as changing the os, install/remove software etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/) to modify a cold VMDK image. It's a good data recovery tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to take a look at this http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/

Comment: this let you mount vmdk offline. there are similar tools in linux but i forgot what it is called even though i used it a long time ago, you may be able to find it by searching though. you can also mount the root disk of one vm to another vm and modify it that way. this is probably safer.